# Independence, Conditional Expectation

Tags: conditional-expectation, uniform-distribution, independence

Problem:
Let $X \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,1)$.
Let $0 < a < b < 1$. Let

$$Y = \begin{cases} 1  & ,\text{ when } 0 < x < b \\ 
 0 &  , \text{ otherwise} \end{cases}$$

and let

$$Z =\begin{cases} 1  &,\text{ when } a < x < 1\\  
0&  ,\text{ otherwise} \end{cases}$$

(a) Are $Y$ and $Z$ independent? Why/Why not?
(b) Find $E(Y|Z)$. Now find $E(Y|Z=z)$.

Attempt:
Let $X$ equal the following:

if $X = a$; then $Y = 1$, $Z = 0$
if $X = b$; then $Y = 0$, $Z = 1$
if $X = \frac{a+b}{2}$; then $Y = 1$, $Z = 1$

Notes:
- I am stuck at this point and do not know where to proceed.
- Any advice on direction would be helpful.
- Question is from "All of Statistics" by Larry Wasserman [Chapter 3, Q22]
- I am also a novice at Math StackExchange: any advice on how to form a proper question would also be useful.

Comment: Why are you unable to find $E(Y | Z)$? Why don't you use the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guide:

- Notice that $Y$ and $Z$ takes binary value.
- To determine if they are independent, note that 
  \begin{align}
  \mathbb{E}(YZ) &= P(a < X < b) \\
  \mathbb{E}(Y) &= P( 0 < X < b) \\
  \mathbb{E}(Z)&=P(a < X< 1)
  \end{align}
- check whether $\mathbb{E}(YZ)$ is equal to $\mathbb{E}(Y)\mathbb{E}(Z)$.
- Note that $\mathbb{E}(Y|Z=0)=\mathbb{E}(Y|0<X<a)=P(0<X<b|0<X<a)$